After upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 laptop bricked
I have a Lenovo Carbon X1 Gen 9 and I have had it for a few years and it has gone through several upgrades. But now after reboot it only shows Memtest86 and there doesn't seem to be anything to boot into! Has anyone encounter this?
At some point during the upgrade I got a warning (a prompt with yes/no) saying that the upgrade is trying to remove currently used kernel and I said not to remove the kernel (thinking I can always upgrade it afterward). Now the laptop is dead. Any help is appreciated.
"everything" was working perfectly fine before upgrade. Now I regret it so badly. The machine can only get into Memtest86 and nothing else. It keeps running it over and over again.
Thanks

OK, I got one step ahead: the problem is that grub launches Memtest86 because it cannot find the kernel. Now why it cannot find the kernel and how to restore it I am still trying. If you know how to fix this situation, or faced the same situation please comment.
Update
I saved myself by creating an installable Ubuntu 24.04 on a USB stick and then copying that kernel onto my machine. I managed to load the kernel from the distro on USB stick, chrooted and install a kernel from repo. Then rebooted the machine. Then Ubuntu 24.04 loaded. But, still a "lot" of stuff was missing. It seems the installer performs post-install steps that I had to do manually, such as installing desktop manager, etc. Finally I am running 24.04.1 but who knows what's missing from 20.04 I was running. I install missing packages on need basis now.
I have been through at least 3 distro upgrades as far as I remember and this was the first time the upgrade nuked my kernel and I was left dangling. I am just saying. It's possible that there was something wrong with my setup but I doubt it.

It's helpful if your specific with details; you mention a release-upgrade but don't mention if your system is a desktop or server install, if you rebooted after completed upgrade and how far you got (eg. I'd expect the grub 2.06 to be replaced by 2.12; was this there as expected?  what exploration did you do there?  did you try and boot to runlevel 1 etc?).  Did you try booting to runlevel 1? if using desktop; does your system operate at terminal level?  What happened if you selected an older kernel?  what kernel stack were you using at 22.04 (GA? HWE?) and will that kernel operate? etc

One option that gets your laptop working again quickly: Make a new 24.04 LiveUSB on a different machine. Boot it. Use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to recover your data. Then reinstall.

"At some point during the upgrade I got a warning (a prompt with yes/no) saying that the upgrade is trying to remove currently used kernel" That's very unusual. That symptom strongly suggests your system was already broken or misconfigured under-the-hood before starting the upgrade, despite seeming "working perfectly fine."

You might want to ensure your system was actually a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system (not a Pop OS 22.04 or other Ubuntu-based) system, as if you read the documentation for Ubuntu-based systems, you'll note they have different release-upgrade procedures as they warn if you run Ubuntu procedures your system will break (Pop OS as example doesn't use Ubuntu kernels, thus what you describe is expected! which is why System76 procedures exist).  This can also happen if your system was Ubuntu, but you added non-Ubuntu packages as per @user535733's last comment...

My system is a desktop (laptop). I didn't check the version of grub, but it is now 2.12. System was not operational at all. There was no kernel image found at all! It was deleted by the upgrade.

My laptop came from Lenovo with Ubuntu installed! I never installed an OS on this system from scratch. So, I am not sure how it can be Pop OS.

I recorded wrong versions in my original posts. I was upgrading 22.04 to 24.04. I must've been really tired when I typed in the message. Anywhow, I am on 24.04 now.

If your laptop wasn't a pure Ubuntu (as in "provided by Lenovo") then I'd actually expect things to go awry; as there might be present "improvements" that are not covered by the upgrade provided by Canonical.
